# Interact with python using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin, stderr

I try to interact to python interpreter using subprocess module like this :

```py
import subprocess


def start(executable_file):
    return subprocess.Popen(
        executable_file,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


def read(process):
    return process.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8").strip()


def write(process, message):
    process.stdin.write(f"{message.strip()}\n".encode("utf-8"))
    process.stdin.flush()


def terminate(process):
    process.stdin.close()
    process.terminate()
    process.wait(timeout=0.2)


process = start("python")
while True:
    write(process, input())
    print(read(process))
terminate(process)
```

But it seems it's locked a deadlock.

If anyone knows how to interact with python with python code and recover stdout, stderr with stream mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `communicate()` rather than `read()` and `write()` with subprocesses else it will lead to deadlock.

See red warning breakout towards middle of [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) page.

Comment: the problem with communicate is you can't write in stdin more then one time
I tried the following code:
`
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

proc = Popen(['python'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
while True:
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(input=input().encode("utf8"))
    print(stdout)
    print(stderr)
`
but i have the next exception:

`
    raise ValueError("Cannot send input after starting communication")
`